# Is it possible to select mic/headset-mic input channels alternately for the L/R channels?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am working on a project that requires both the headset mic and built in mic to record a stereo file where the left channel is from the headset mic and the right channel is from the built in mic only.

Is this possible?